# How to Calculate Word Frequency by Date in Dataframe

Tags: twitter, word-frequency

So I have a Dataframe of thousands of tweets that I was able to clean and tokenize.
-Each row is an individual Tweet
-Column 1 is the day they were tweeted (example: 7_23_2020)
-Column 2 is the individual tokenized bag of words of each Tweet

Goal: How can I tabulate the word frequencies for each day and then graph them?
For example: What are the frequencies of top 10 words from (7_23_2020 - 7_30_2020)?
Showing how frequently the word was used each day?

Originally I needed to calculate the PMI (Pointwise Mutual Information) between the dates and most common words but I think i am just settling for word frequencies across time now.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you’re going to create a bulleted list, you need to put them in a separate paragraph so they don’t end up flowing